# Avoid lexicographic ordering in badger DB

Tags: database, badgerdb

By default values in the badger database are stored lexicographically, is there a way to avoid this behavior and store them in a normal orderly fashion (FIFO) ?

Answer (score 0):

No

prefix the key with an increasing ID to get them in fifo order

You can use something https://github.com/artiship/rocks-queue-java like this and model it in badger db